# Dropbox Core SDK for iOS using access token

Tags: ios, iphone, dropbox

I need to upload files from my iOS application into my Dropbox account. I'm following this tutorial to do so: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios. But I don't understand how to use the generated access token to access my own account without going through the authentication flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated access token available on the [Dropbox App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) is an OAuth 2 access token, just meant as a shortcut to let your app to your own account. The Dropbox iOS Core SDK uses OAuth 1 though, so you can't use the generated access token with it. That being the case, you'll need to implement the app authorization flow so that you, and additionally your end-users, can link your iOS app to their Dropbox accounts, as shown in the [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios).

If you only ever need to link to your own account, you'll still need to process the app authorization flow for your own account once to get an OAuth 1 access token.